# Error when updating image in ms access

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I update the image in ms access i get this error:

> coulddn't find d/bin/debug/openfilediloge1

and when I choose another image I get

> couldn't save currently lockedby another user

my code as follow.

```
Private Sub Btnedit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnedit.Click
    'Dim d As New DAL
    'd.Dataedit("delete from labdetails")
    'Pic.Image = Nothing
    'MsgBox("من فضلك اختر صورة")

    '    btnsave_Click(Nothing, Nothing)



    Try
        Dim fsreader As New FileStream(dlgpics.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)

        Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
        breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
        fsreader.Close()
        Dim strsql As String
        Dim acscmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con = New OleDbConnection(("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath() & "\lab2015.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mak;"))

        strsql = "update labdetails set labnme=@labnme,labspecial=@labspecial,labadress=@labadress,labphone=@labphone,labtime=@labtime,lablogo=@lablogo,labprint=@labprint,labnameenglish=@labnameenglish,labspecialenglish=@labspecialenglish"
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acscmd.Connection = con


        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labnme", txtlabname.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labspecial", txtspeciality.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labadress", txtadress.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labphone", txtphone.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labtime", txttime.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lablogo", imgbuffer)
        '  If printchck.Checked = True Then
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labprint", printchck.Checked)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labnameenglish", Txtlab.Text)
        acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labspecialenglish", txtspecial.Text)
        ' Else
        ' acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labprint", "No")
        ' End If

        con.Open()
        acscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        acscmd.Dispose()
        Me.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    labdetails_Load(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub
```

Comment: You arent disposing of the streams, but `buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(...)` should be all you need to get the image bytes

Comment: could you edit my code ?

Comment: at what line in the code are you getting those messages?  Have you tired the debugger to see what is happening at the point of these errors?

Comment: Dim fsreader As New FileStream(dlgpics.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)